# Should I split this Django project into two projects?

Tags: django

I have a Django project. It was always intended to have two separate forward facing URLs.
One was for teachers, and one was for students.
A teacher can post assignments, wait for students to do it, and then review the work.
Both sites have very different functionality.

Currently, having the code be in a single project is becoming increasingly hairy. Students can signup in a lazy way (i.e. after doing work) but teachers cannot. I have complicated logic to make sure that the user is the correct role when signing up and showing views. Teachers and students each have a different kind of Profile (so I currently can't use AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE). I don't care if I have seperate Tables for the two kinds of users. In fact, I prefer that.

If I were to split this into two projects, I believe a lot of things would be conceptually simpler. The only problem is that, when a teacher submits an assignment, I would need to need to post that assignment to the student site somehow. But synchronizing the content would be much simpler than keeping two types of users in the same code. (The synchronization only happens in two places, and besides that the two sites have *very* different functionality and models and apps.)

Should I break this into two projects? If so, what is a secure way to share data from one Django site to another?

Answer (score 0):

I think splitting it into two projects is going to create far more problems then it solves and (from my limited knowledge of the app) I don't think that it would make sense to do so - the two users are a part of a single homework submission and marking system/application and therefore they should be developed as such. Just because it might make your job easier doesn't mean it is the correct move.

Are you using inheritance? Have you written or utilized extra permissions? It sounds like you could clean up your two conceptually different profiles using decorators, middleware and a custom AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE implementation.

Comment: I am downvoting you because you didn't really explain why this would be worse. "create far more problems then it solves" Like what? "doesn't mean it is the correct move?" Why not? "Are you using inheritance?" Yes, in profiles.

Comment: How can I give give concrete examples if you haven't provided any details of your implementation? If you split your application into two separate projects you will essentially have to program them as if they are two separate entities communicating over the internet which will be infinitely more difficult then if they are sharing the same codebase. You will have to write two separate APIs for them to talk to each other on.

Comment: As I said, there is minimal communication required, and besides that the codebases will be very distinct.